# Is there any difference between the pronunciation of "Write" and "Right"?

Tags: pronunciation

I made a little research but I found very difficult to discriminate their pronunciation. Also, I think that in informal speech it's harder to distinguish than in a slow and clear voice.

Then, in practice, Is there any difference between the pronunciation of "Write" and "Right"? Or the difference comes through the context that they are placed in.

In addition, if you could help me with a non-specific question:

Should I try to be more clear in my pronunciation rather than try to be more similar to native (US, UK, etc.) pronunciation?

I ask this because sometimes when I try to speak with a better pronunciation (like trying to remove my portuguese accent), it turns out to be more unclear, indistinguishable.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you doing your English speaking, and who are you speaking to?

Comment: Those words are: homophones, they are homophonic. [fyi, do research, not make research]. I suggest not trying to remove one's accent. I suggest trying to copy an accent. That is a more positive approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**Right**" and "**Write**" are both pronounced as [raɪt]. There is no difference in pronunciation by grammar defaults, however, depending on the dialect it may slightly vary.

Concerning your additional question, two things should be cleared out:

1. Try to be as clear as possible and try to sound lucid so anybody can understand the words you speak.
2. Try to bring in some British or American accent into your voice little by little without ruining your clarity.

I, myself, am not a native speaker but I always try to copy people who speak fluently and with clarity. I especially love book reader. Their voice and clarity is almost always amazing.

Comment: Sometimes, a French, German, Italian, Portuguese or whatever other accent adds color to the speech and makes the English language sound great. Take **Enrique Iglesias** as an example. His English pronunciation has that Spanish influence that makes his voice sound so daisy in songs.

Answer (score 3):

(At least in BrE, and I'm pretty sure elsewhere) There is no difference in pronunciation between "right" and "write", it's all about context.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a difference in speaking the words 'write' and 'right'. 'Write' is spoken with the lips more pursed and 'right' is spoken with tongue further back in the mouth pointing upward toward hard palate. There must be a difference in sound but difficult for most to distinguish. Maybe the differences do lie in dialectic differences, I speak with a Southern accent.

Comment: Even with a southern accent, these homophones.

Comment: Do not agree with you.

Comment: Wha, honey, my mamma was from Tennessee and Ah spent a lotta time there when Ah was young. Ah really cain't [ok, that's exaggerated] tell the diffrence. :)

Comment: Reminds me (a Brit) that I once had to ask an American several times when he said "cairn" whether he meant "can" or "can't".